# How can call multiple function in React ternary if else condition

Tags: reactjs

I can not call multiple functions in react js if else ternary condition.

```
const preATCHandler = ( id, itemNumber ) => {

    itemNumber > 0
        ?    (setAtcBtn(false), setQty(itemNumber), dispatch(addToCart(id, Number(itemNumber))))
        :    (dispatch(removeFromCart(id)), setAtcBtn(true))

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason it must be a ternary operator and cannot be an if-else block?

Answer (score 1):

I can not call multiple functions in ternary operator because it is inline condition.
Finaly take help from wxker.
I use this.

```
 const preATCHandler = ( id, itemNumber ) => {
         if (itemNumber){
            setAtcBtn(false);
            dispatch(addToCart(id, Number(itemNumber)));
         }else {
           dispatch(removeFromCart(id));
           setAtcBtn(true);
         }
      

}
```